# Unable to construct VERIFY_PIN_DIRECT control command

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, openpgp, pcsc

I'm writing a JAVA-app to access my OpenPGP-Card V2.0. The card terminal im using is a "REINER SCT cyberJack RFID standard" which only supports PC/SC under OSX, and now I want to implement the PC/SC 2.0-command "VERIFY_PIN_DIRECT".

I tried the following control sequence, the bytes after the | are the APDU-bytes (my testing pin is "140396"):

```
Index: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 | 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
Seq 0: 0F 0F 88 86 14 08 04 02 01 09 04 00 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 | 00 20 00 81 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

Some important byte meanings (useful doc: http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/1207/API-ACR83-1.06.pdf):

```
Index 02: PIN format options
Index 03: PIN-block format
Index 04: Position of PIN-length information in the APDU-command
Index 15 - 18: APDU-length
Index 19 - end: APDU-command
```

But if I send this command, I always get `69 82` which means accordingly to the [OpenPGP-Card datasheet (PDF)](http://g10code.com/docs/openpgp-card-2.0.pdf):

> Security status not satisfied:
>
> PW wrong
>
> PW not checked (command not allowed)
>
> Secure messaging incorrect (checksum and/or cryptogram)

The APDU-command seems to be correct, because if I send the following command `00 20 00 81 06 31 34 30 33 39 36` to the card, the PIN is accepted. So it seems my control-command is wrong. Where is my mistake?

**Update:**

A working command is:

```
Index: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 | 19 20 21 22
Seq 0: 0F_0F 02_0F_00 0F_06 02 01 09_04 00 00_00_00 04_00_00_00 | 00 20 00 81
```

A better value then `0F_06` (at index `05`) would be `20_06` because the OpenPGP-Card supports PINs up to a length of 32 chars, but my card terminal complains `Invalid Value`...

**P.S.:** The underscores symbolize related bytes and are of course stripped out during parsing.

Comment: Does the PIN entry dialogue appear on the readers display? In any case the APDU looks strange, I would recommend to take a look at [pcsc-part10](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/files/pcsc10_v2.02.09.pdf) for reference.

Comment: The PIN-dialogue appears on the reader ("PIN") and the APDU works, if I send it directly to the card via JAVA's CardChannel.transmit(APDU byte array)... and thanks for the reference, I hadn't found this one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenPGP uses variable length PIN and the PIN block must by popular convention (this case is not covered in the CCID specification) be sent as *empty* APDU with only the APDU header.

See here for a hint: https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/blob/master/src/libopensc/reader-pcsc.c#L1391

Also, is your app open source? Maybe you want to contribute some CCID control block code which I've not yet written to apdu4j: https://github.com/martinpaljak/apdu4j

Comment: Thank you a lot! Yeah, my app will be opensource and I will be happy to commit to your codebase when I have finished my little app :D
I will test your solution tomorrow and then (hopefully) accept it :)
I also found this helpful documentation: http://www2.electron.frba.utn.edu.ar/~afurfaro/descargas/Universal%20Serial%20Bus/Especificaciones%20de%20clases/ChipSmart%20Card%20Interface%20Devices%20(CCID)/ccid_classspec_1_00a.pdf

Comment: Well it worked, my control command is "0F_0F 02_0F_00 0F_06 02 01 09_04 00 00_00_00 04_00_00_00 | 00 20 00 81"